# How would I take an excel file and convert its columns into lists in Python?

Tags: python, excel, list, import, translate

I had the following question. Namely, suppose I have an excel file with some names in the first row. Then the next however many rows are single letter entries (so "A", "B", "C" and so on).

My goal is to extract the column and make it into a list, so that, say, for column 1 the list would start in row 2, the next entry would be from row 3, and so on, until the end is reached.

How would I do that in Python?

Comment: Your title sounds like a simple transpose which Excel can already do, but the question itself describes something I'm not clear on: the list for the first column would contain the whole column (excluding the header row), but the list for the last column would be missing the first `row_length` entries? Can you provide sample input and output?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, no, every list would contain the entire column except for the first row.

Comment: So just transpose it in Excel?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, I still need to convert it to the list, that's what I don't (or didn't) know.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, the question has nothing to do with transposing rows and columns, so I don't know why you're downvoting it and the answer that helped me.

Comment: Turning columns into rows is exactly what transposition does. I downvoted this question because the question's body makes it sounds like you're eliminating a row for each successive column (and it looks like you yourself still don't understand your goals and what transposition does), and I downvoted the current answer because it does not answer the question. All it does is suggest a library to use. Library recommendations are off-topic for SO, and leaving one as an answer just because one does not have sufficient reputation to comment is exploiting SO's reputation privilege system.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, but my goal is not to turn columns into rows as is evident from my question. The title itself says I want to turn columns into lists.

Comment: Spreadsheets are generally parsed as a 2D list where each sublist is a row. A transposition flips the data so that rows are columns and vice versa. This would allow each column to be seen as a row, for easy parsing (assuming you actually want to work with the data in Python rather than just transpose your data, which isn't clear). Note how the current answer doesn't say anything about rows, columns, transposition, or lists. Future readers who want to accomplish this task will find nothing here but a recommendation for a library they were probably already using.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, OK, whatever, I answered my own question down below and at least Sonder's answer was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer. Assuming the Excel file is *Test.xlsx*, we can translate the j-th column (excluding the first row) into list_j as follows:

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook("Test.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

list_j = []

for k in range(1,sheet.nrows):
    list_j.append(str(sheet.row_values(k)[j-1]))
```

Answer (score 3):

I used a module called **xlrd**.

Some information on that http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/04/30/reading-excel-spreadsheets-with-python-and-xlrd/

And here is the package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd

To exclude the first row, and make different lists for different columns you could do something like...

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

book = open_workbook("mydata.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0) #If your data is on sheet 1

column1 = []
column2 = []
#...

for row in range(1, yourlastrow): #start from 1, to leave out row 0
    column1.append(sheet.cell(row, 0)) #extract from first col
    column2.append(sheet.cell(row, 1))
    #...
```

Put the index-1 of the last row that contains data in the 'yourlastrow' placeholder.

Comment: The question was about transposing rows and columns, not about what libraries can read and write Excel files. This doesn't answer the question, and would be better suited as a comment. You will be able to leave a comment when you have sufficient reputation.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed.