# How to have multi index on both rows and columns of a dataframe without using tuples?

Tags: python, pandas, label, multi-index

Is there a way to create a dataframe having multi-indexing on both rows and columns without using tuples? My labels are too long to enter manually as tuples (96 countries and 26 sectors per country).
[Example of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjWqC.jpg)

I tried:

```
df_data.columns=label_df 

df_data_w = pd.concat([label_df, data],axis=1,ignore_index=False)
```

This added the label df to the first two columns, but didn't index it. I instead get this following [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8RlL.jpg)

Here is some code to use:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)
b = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)
c = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)
d = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)
e = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)
f = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)
g = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)
h = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)
i = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i])

Continent = ['Africa','Africa','Africa','North America', 'North America', 'North America', 'Europe','Europe','Europe']

Sectors = ['Agriculture','Industry','Domestic','Agriculture','Industry','Domestic','Agriculture','Industry','Domestic']

label_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[Continent, Sectors])

df.columns=label_df  

df_w_labels = pd.concat([label_df, data],axis=1,ignore_index=False)`
```

This gives me the labels as headers in my df, but I need them as columns as well, so I tried concat, which added the label df to the first two columns, but didn't index it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**. That means no links, no images, just text in your question. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @jpp - my first SO post. Have edited to hopefully be more helpful.

Comment: To clarify, while you have a lot of labels you have only two levels, correct? "Country" and "sector"?

Comment: Hi @Ajean yes, only two levels: Country and Sector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip` and `list` with `pd.MultiIndex`:

```
a = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)
b = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)
c = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)
d = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)
e = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)
f = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)
g = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)
h = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)
i = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,size=9)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i])

Continent = ['Africa','Africa','Africa','North America', 'North America', 'North America', 'Europe','Europe','Europe']
Sectors = ['Agriculture','Industry','Domestic','Agriculture','Industry','Domestic','Agriculture','Industry','Domestic']

indx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(Continent,Sectors)))

df.index = indx
df.columns = indx

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks Scott Boston, that’s helpful. I think my main issue is turning the columns in my .csv file into tuples, as the labels in my real data set are too long to enter manually (96 countries with 26 sectors each). Am going to try the xlrd package described here and report on results:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403460/how-would-i-take-an-excel-file-and-convert-its-columns-into-lists-in-python